# Is REST a preferred choice?

Tags: rest

A concern while understanding the REST protocol, so thought to reach out experts here. Please clarify. 
REST advices not to maintain server state. REST also advices to fetch resources hierarchically, one level at a time. Considering both, is the server deemed to face difficulty to keep re-fetching records from DB instead of filtering the already existing chunk. For example, if any application has to fetch a Continent information, the REST form of URL will be http://host:port/fetchSomeInfo/ContinentName. As a response, the app returns All Countries name and client is happy with that. Trouble starts from here, when further details are needed. On the response content, if the Client queries on any Country to get the Cities within, now the REST URL will take the form http://host:port/fetchSomeInfo/ContinentName/CountryName. Since server doesn't maintain state, it has to re-run the DB query with ContinentName and CountryName. Stepping further, the query re-run happens at each level, City info in a Country, Area info in a City. The more the hierarchy goes, the more AND conditions gets added to the DB Query and re-run the query each time. Is this a good design strategy?

Comment: `REST` is an architectural style. Not protocol. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

Comment: Thanks for correcting Ivan. Yes, I should have told _REST design_ instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily. The central concept of RESTful APIs is that each resource has a unique URI. Typically, you'll use paths that allow for fast data retrieval, such as PK values.

In your example of getting a Specific continent with a specific country, the more proper URI would be:
**http://host/Continents/continentID/Countries/countryID**

The consumer of the RESTful API has the responsibility of knowing the ID of the continent for which he wants to get countries. (*you could also provide convenience interface in your API*).

So a consumer of the RESTful service would:

1. GET http://host/continents
2. Search the continent data to obtain the desired continent ID
3. GET http://host/continents/id/countries
4. Search the country data to get the desired country id
5. GET http://host/continents/id/countries/id

But the consumer is also free to STORE ids for future reference, thus allowing him to directly do: `GET http://host/continents/id/countries/id`

As for your worry about *re-running DB queries*, since RESTful services don't maintain state, they consume far less resources. They're essentially Database-heavy services. But Relational Databases are extremely optimized for data retrieval, especially when properly indexed for common query conditions.

In such a situation, I'd stress a common suggestion:
**Avoid early optimization, it will kill your project. Optimize when the need to optimize arises**

All in all, if your RESTful service is well designed and your DB well structured, I doubt you'll hit any performance issues because of repetitive DB queries.

Comment: Thank you. This explains well. We got this concern as we are trying to update the proposal design document and wanted to see if we need to highlight if this design will query DB each time with all fields even for the hierarchical calls.

Comment: Whether the service returns ALL data columns or not is up to you. In the example in case, I would suggest returning a limited list of information when getting all "countries", such as `id,name,continent_id` as that information is sufficiently useful from a "list" perspective. But that is subjective and in the end is up to you.

Comment: Another question-can URL contain _control switches_ following REST design principles? For example, cities within a country should be returned as XML or JSON basing on the choice. SO can we say that while using REST, it is allowed to use this form or URL?
http://host:port/countries/countryid/cities?format=XML.
Anymore params are allowed in this manner? using traditional URL concatenation using &. Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes you can. However, many such parameters should be provided as request headers.

Comment: Very much helpful and quick responses. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than exposing internal details, RESTfulness describes the behaviour of the service. It should hence *behave* stateless. What you are asking in your question in plain words is "can I use caching although I am implementing a restful service?". Answer is yes. As long as your service behaves correctly.

Comment: Thanks, but the whole view point is to avoid caching, thus RESTful design came into picture, to make server stateless.

Comment: probably it's a good idea to rethink some parts, seems that there's some confusion between different types of approach / strategies and technical implementation details...